# Why am I observing additional trailing digits when using read.csv in R?

Tags: r, read.table, read.csv

I am reading a large numeric data from csv. The values have trailing zeroes. When importing the data using `read.csv`, additional digits are appended to the end of the number.

Reproducible example:

```
> options(digits = 22)
> number <- as.character("19.745130761412300000000000000000")
> print(number)
[1] "19.745130761412300000000000000000"

> write.csv(number, "number.csv")
> read.csv("number.csv")
  X                  x
1 1 19.745130761412302
```

Note the 02 at the end of x.

This behaviour also occurs when using `as.numeric`:

```
> number <- as.character("19.745130761412300000000000000000")
> print(number)
[1] "19.745130761412300000000000000000"
> as.numeric(number)
[1] 19.745130761412302
```

How can I avoid the extra digits when importing many data? Removing the trailing zeroes prior to `read.csv` is not an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: R can't track that many digits accurately (which is really just a limit of the standard numeric "double" variable type). What are you doing that so many digits are required? Are they really numeric values to you?

Comment: Related: [why are these numbers not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) and [how many decimals of pi do we need](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2016/3/16/how-many-decimals-of-pi-do-we-really-need/)

Comment: Try setting this option before reading. `options(scipen = 999)`

Comment: @giraffehere R 3.4.3, Windows 10. The result still ends with 02.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numerals = "no.loss"` :

```
write.csv("19.745130761412300000000000000000", "number.csv")
dd <- read.csv("number.csv", numerals = "no.loss")

print(dd, digits = 22)
##   X                                 x
## 1 1 19.745130761412300000000000000000

str(dd)
## 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ X: int 1
##  $ x: Factor w/ 1 level "19.745130761412300000000000000000": 1
```

See the `numerals` argument in `?type.convert` for details.